# Share box shows different UI on different situations

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

In MSE the share option box behaves differently.

When we click on the text field, it slightly expands and a border appears around the text field

[image: Focus]

If we click outside the box, it shrinks slightly and the text field border disappears.

[image: Outside]

Is this status-by-design or a small bug ? I checked on SO and MSO, there is no such behavior on those sites. (Note : I like MSE's design, wonderful UI design and looks very good)

**More Info:**

```
OS      : Windows 7
Browser : Firefox 23
```